# How do i arrange 20 buttons in a format of 5 rows and 4 columns in HTML with a decent amount of space between the columns?

Tags: html, css

I have created a webpage which has 20 buttons in a random row format. I want to make in a format of columns with a decent amount of space such as one column in the left the other in the center and respectively. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: You could start by sharing your code, so it's easier for us to help you

Comment: show what did you try so far.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Retail Catalog Troubleshooting Guide " button style="cursor:pointer;background-color:lightyellow" onclick="window.open('https://csi.amazon.com/diag/Retail_Catalog_Troubleshooting_Guide?resourcePath=Retail_Catalog_Troubleshooting_Guide&diag_run_id=cc87a9f8-dc8d-4759-980f-0d8c1ef67646/')"/>

This is one button i'm not able to add the code as it is too big, please copy the line of code and use it for the rest 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, I hope you are looking something like This below fiddle. If you want it using html then see [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5zwgsb5v/2/) with HTML:

```css
#outer {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
#outer2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
#outer2 .inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
#outer3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
#outer3 .inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
#outer4 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 4px;
}
#outer4 .inner {
  display: inline-block;
}
#btndiv {
  margin: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="btndiv">
  <div id="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="msgBtnBack">button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer2">
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="msgBtnBack">button</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="outer3">
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="msgBtnBack">button</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="outer4">
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button type="submit" class="msgBtn2" onClick="return false;">button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      <button class="msgBtnBack">button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use bootstrap buttons same like this your question was about to create this by using html so I did this with html.You can add customize  design as your desire.

Hope it will help you.

**For extra padding:**

```
#outer2 .inner {
    padding: 2px; 
}
```

Can add `padding-top`, `padding-right`, etc I just add the padding for all. Thats it.

Comment: Thank you so much it is really helpful. But how to add space between the columns

Comment: thanks glad to help you .You can use padding css  to add space between the buttons according to your wish .see the edited ans

Comment: Thank you. I have created the webpage.